# Is there a way of using JavaScript libraries in Azure DocumentDB server code?

Tags: javascript, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'm writing some trigger code in Azure DocumentDB.

Is there a way of using/referencing JavaScript libraries (such as [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)) within server Stored Procedures, Triggers and User Defined Functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can embed common functions within stored procedure code - granted it fits inside the [256kb limit](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/) for a stored procedure.

For your example, underscore is only 6kb minified and can be embedded inside a sproc.

Note: keep in mind server-side scripts are resource governed (you may hit request timeout and/or cpu limits for long running scripts).

Comment: I had hoped that there was a way of adding external references within server code rather than embedding but this answer is helpful, thank you. I was going to add a feature request but see you did already - thanks! :)

Comment: Where are feature requests posted?

Comment: Right here: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/7724601-the-ability-to-reference-javascript-libraries-e-g